# scan Wi-Fi networks with android emulator

Tags: virtual-machine, android, emulator

I am trying to use an android app on a emulator from windows and I need to be able to connect the "phone" directly to a Wi-Fi network while the emulator only shows its guest wifi. Is there a way to have it scan all nearby wifis and connect to one.

My second option would be to use Androidx86 on a VM but iI have the same problem.

Or I could try running Android off of a USB but I can not get it to boot up

Comment: You need to understand that both emulation and virtualization will use the available internet connection.

Comment: Android emulator never sees real Wifi networks. The only way would be to use an USB dongle and to forward the USB device into the guest OS, but that would require VirtualBox and I don't think the guest images are prepared to use an USB stick. Conclusion: Use a real Android phone.

Comment: @Robert Not true, there are Android emulators that do support this function.  Admittingly, however, the feature can be obscure and difficult to dig up and configure properly, e.g., MEmu has a separate multi-instance manager client that's included in the installation directory (no mention anywhere in their documentation) that you can use to manage USB passthroughs.

Answer (score 1):

The way I found that this can be done is to use Prime OS in a virtual machine.
Since Prime OS comes with the drivers for many USB Wi-Fi dongles pre installed this is easily to accomplish if you have an external Wi-Fi USB.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In order to scan the scanner must have access to the hardware of the wireless card and must be able to get information about the wireless networks.

Viruralized hardware does not get this information usually, unless you've configured a pass through that is supported.

Even when using a pass through the Viruralized software must be able to recognize and control the hardware, so there would need to be drivers, and the hardware would have to be able to understand the software's commands.

All this means it is very likely you will not be able to do what you are trying to do.